# Что я делаю не так? (Архиватор)

Tags: java

Учу Java, решил написать что-то типа архиватора.
Собственно в `output` вводим путь и название архива, типа : `C://Folder/arhiv.zip`
Дальше происходит что-то ужасное. В `file` считываем путь к файлу который нам нужно закинуть в архив ( Типа : `C://SomeFolder/text.txt`). Если там написано `STOP`, значит все файлы введены и больше ничего толкать в архив не нужно. Ниже создаём `ZipOutputStream` который принимает наш `output` и `FileInputStream` который принимает файлы которые нужно поместить в архив. Создаём `ZipEntry`, в него толкаем названия считываемых файлов. Чтобы названия в архиве были такими же что были при считывании. Открываем `putNextEntry`. Тут создаём массив байтов равный считываемому файлу и считываем его. Записываем его в `output` и закрываем `Entry`.

Вся проблема в том, что в архив попадает только последний введённый файл. Ввожу 2-3 файла, но в архиве остаётся только последний введённый. Что я делаю не так?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Куда архив сохранять?");
   String output = in.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Укажите путь к файлу который нужно поместить в архив");
   System.out.println("Когда вы введёте все файлы, введите STOP");

   for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

       File file = new File(in.nextLine());
       if (file.getName().equals("STOP")){
           System.exit(4);
       }

       try (ZipOutputStream zipout = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output));
            FileInputStream zipin = new FileInputStream(file)) {
           ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.getName());
           zipout.putNextEntry(entry);
           byte[] buffer = new byte[zipin.available()];
           zipin.read(buffer);
           zipout.write(buffer);
           zipout.closeEntry();
       }
       catch(IOException ex){
           System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
       }
   }
}
```

}

---

Открыл и закрыл zipout вне цикла, теперь копирует только первый файл введённый в список для архиватора. И копирует его странно, файл весит 0кб.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Куда архив сохранять?");

    String output = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Укажите путь к файлу который нужно поместить в архив");

    System.out.println("Когда вы введёте все файлы, введите STOP");

    try (ZipOutputStream zipout = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output))) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

            File file = new File(in.nextLine());
            if (file.getName().equals("STOP")) {
                System.exit(4);
            }

            try (FileInputStream zipin = new FileInputStream(file)) {

                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.getName());

                zipout.putNextEntry(entry);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[zipin.available()];

                zipin.read(buffer);

                zipout.write(buffer);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        zipout.closeEntry();
    }

    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: дело в том, что вы постоянно перезаписываете архив) открывайте `ZipOutputStream` до цикла формирования файлов и закрывайте после цикла. У вас `ZipOutputStream` зажат в `try with resources`.  То есть после выхода из блока `try catch` он закрывается. Потом в новом витке цикла открывается заново(перезаписыва я старый) и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

У вас на каждый файл создается новый объект `zipout`, который с каждым новым файлом перезаписывается. Нужно создать `zipout` до цикла и закрыть после:

```
    ZipOutputStream zipout = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

        File file = new File(in.nextLine());
        if (!(file.getName().equals("STOP"))) {
            try (FileInputStream zipin = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.getName());
                zipout.putNextEntry(entry);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[zipin.available()];
                zipin.read(buffer);
                zipout.write(buffer);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }

        } else {
            zipout.closeEntry();
            System.exit(4);
        }
    }
```

Так же нужно дополнить декларацию метода main():

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
```

Comment: Не выходит.
`FileOutputStream` просит `FileNotFoundException` а `CloseEntry` `IOException` . Или это как то можно обойти? Не вписав это всё в try catch?

Comment: Открыл и закрыл zipout вне цикла, теперь копирует только первый файл введённый в список для архиватора. И копирует его странно, файл весит 0кб.

Comment: Нужно к методу main() дописать ``throws IOException``.

Comment: Что при `throws`, что через `try catch` работает.
Но теперь в другую сторону. теперь в архив влетает только первый файл который был введён в список архивируемых файлов. Что странно, файл весит 0 кб да и вообще выглядит как ярлык на оригинальный.

Comment: Я немного подправил код. Он рабочий, но с одной ошибкой - последний файл хоть и есть показывается в архиве, но его содержимое отсутствует. По-быстрому не смог найти в чем проблема. Но изначальная проблема (сохраняется только один файл) решена.

Comment: `System.exit(4);` замените на `break;` Именно в коде что в этом ответе. Проверил - работает(ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)` - тут что, никто не умеет писать `while (true)`?

Comment: или `while(!nextLine.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP"))`

Comment: @Chubatiy, да, поток при таком выходе не закрывается. А чего ответ писать не стал?

Comment: @Qwertiy, а смысл? Уже пытаются помочь. А примерно одно и то же писать смысла нет. Лучше попытаюсь натолкнуть в комментах на мысль